# Sort letters in huge string

Tags: sorting

I have a 16 MB text document containing a single huge string of letters and numbers without any separators. Excerpt: "as81jsa8sm1o1kmka9s93m1l"

Is there a simple way to alphabetize all of the characters, without having to write a script? I'm afraid JS will crash under the weight of the file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you do it on the server side?

Comment: There's a simple and fast way to alphabetize it, but "without a script"? What does that mean?

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic way to alphabetize the characters? or a way to alphabetize the characters without using a program? Is your language preference javascript?

Comment: I'm simply looking for the simplest way possible to alphabetize my huge document. Doing it in terminal, using javascript, whatever turns out to be the simplest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the string only contains letters and numbers, you can use a bucket sort and achieve good performance.

I am not sure what language you are using, so I'll assume you can read the string character by character. my solution is psuedocode

```
int[] buckets = int[36]; // 26 for letters, 10 for numbers; assuming only lowercase characters
while(string.hasNext()) {
  char x = next character in string;
  if(x.isAlpha()) {
    buckets[x-'a']++;
  }else {
    buckets[26 + x - '0']++
  }

}
```

To print out the sorted string:

```
string s = ""; // at the end of the loops, s will contain the sorted string
for(int i =0 ; i < 26; ++i) {
  int y = buckets[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
    s+=(y+'a');
  }

}
for(int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i) {
  int y = buckets[i+26];
  for(int j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
    s+=(y+'0');
  }

}
```